# R shiny does't work in the server but can work well locally

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

R shiny can run well locally but nothing shows up in the web server except for the ui.(All graph areas are blank)

Logs:
The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:
runExample
The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:
The following objects are masked from ‘package:lubridate’:

I found this in the Chrome inspector:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of null
>
> at ShinyApp.$sendMsg (shinyapp.js:310)
>
> at ShinyApp.sendInput (shinyapp.js:140)
> at input_rate.js:210

Comment: It happened to me once. I only had to change my app from a `single file` to a `multiple files` app. Is your app in a single file? or you have an `ui.R` an `server.R` files?

Comment: I have two files. Server.r and ui.r

Comment: In fact, it can work well on the web server yesterday but I don't know what's wrong with it today.

Comment: Hello @Johan Rosa did you find a solution?

Comment: I did, @AmanyirahoRobinson, but that was long ago.